# How can I show images on google maps for Android Studio

Tags: android

I searched a lot about that but I didn't get what I want.

I'm using Android Studio and I know how to use google maps and GPS but I want to put a camera icon to use the camera in the phone and when the user take a picture the app will save that action and mark the location and show that photo on the map like (Instagram maps).

Thank you.

Comment: Use a framelayout and put your image on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the areas that you need to work with in Android:

Camera and taking a picture

- https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Displaying information on maps (image like instagram)

- https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

When the picture is taken you can try and pull the location using the **ExifInterface**.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

From there you can get the lat/long and place that image as a point on the map.